# React native Elements Input full width

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I was trying to implement the Input from React Native Elements, which is the blue one. I want to make the Input have full width within the red view.
So I did

width: '100%', marginHorizontal: 0, padding: 0, and alignItems: 'stretch' independently.

But none of them didn't work. What is the problem?
This is the screenshot of the screen

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDhuC.png]

And this is the corresponding code

```
    <View style = {styles.campusInputView}>
      <Input
        containerStyle = {styles.campusInputContainer}
        inputStyle = {styles.campusInput}
        placeholder = 'KAIST'
        editable = {false}
      />
    </View>
```

with the style

```
  campusInputView: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'red',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: height * 100 / 640,
    left: width * 45 / 360,
    width: width * 270 / 360,
  },
  campusInputContainer: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'green',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  campusInput: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'blue',
    flex: 1,
    fontFamily: 'NanumSquareB',
    fontSize: 20,
    paddingVertical: 0,
  },
```

Answer (score 12):

Overwriting `paddingHorizontal` of `containerStyle` as `0` makes the input full width.
Overwriting only `padding` as `0` is not enough.

```js
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements'

<Input
  containerStyle = {{ paddingHorizontal: 0 }}
  // other settings
/>
```

Comment: Wow. This must be accepted answer... I don't know why when I overwrite `padding` it does not work but when I tried `paddingHorizontal` it works perfectly!!

Comment: I agree, this should be an accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

You should add `paddingHorizontal: 0` to `campusInputContainer`

```
campusInputContainer: {
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: 'green',
  alignItems: 'stretch',
  paddingHorizontal: 0
},
```

Answer (score -1):

The `width` you want is `100%`. And I set the color of the `border` to `red`.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';



export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
     <View style = {styles.campusInputView}>
      <Input
        containerStyle = {styles.campusInputContainer}
        inputStyle = {styles.campusInput}
        placeholder = 'KAIST'
        editable = {false}
      />
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  campusInputView: {
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:"center",
    alignItems:"center"
  },
  campusInputContainer: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'red',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  campusInput: {
    flex: 1,
    fontFamily: 'NanumSquareB',
    fontSize: 20,
    paddingVertical: 0,
  },
});
```